# "You are wonderful, [everything included]."

Tags: phrase-requests

This is for a letter to a person very close to me.
I'm trying to figure out the right way to say the part between brackets:
"You are a wonderful person, [everything included]."

I'm trying to express that the person may have "issues" (in their own words), but that their existence does not change how I think about them.

How can I best say this without altering the first part of the sentence?
What I don't want is to make the sentence about those issues, just gently hint at them.

So NOT: "You have problems, but.."

But more like Xanne's suggestion: "You are wonderful, just as you are."

Answer (score 1):

You could say:
"You are a wonderful person, all things considered."

Or perhaps consider rearranging the sentence so that it ends on the positive point, eg:
"Despite some of your quirks, you are a wonderful person."

Answer (score 0):

You are a wonderful person, though not 100% perfect.

---

You are a wonderful person in spite of a few blemishes.

---

Here is my **latest update**:

**foible**  from 
**OALD**

> n.  small, usu harmless, peculiarity or weakness in a person's character

When I had my first glimpse of the definition of this word, your question came into my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are wonderful just as you are.

Answer (score -1):

You are a wonderful person in in **almost** every way imaginable.